# Can a program run in the pycharm console forever

Tags: pycharm

my question is basically the title.

Can a program run "forever" in the pycharm console or will it be interupted after some time.

Im running some tests that would be nice to run over a couple of days.

BONUS QUESTION:
I've selected that pycharm should save my logs, but that does not seem to happen when I stop the programs from pycharm. Is there a way to make pycharm save the logs even if I stop the program from the outside?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it wouldn't run infinitely but just to make sure run it in your console :).